# Why does Thea forget who the Arrow is in season 3?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, arrow

In season 3, episode 13, Thea finally learns that her brother, Oliver Queen is the Arrow.

But I thought that Thea already found out who the Arrow is at the end of season 2. At one of the end episodes of season 2, Thea learns the secret of both her mother ***and her brother***. This triggers her disappointment in her family members and she decides to get away with her biological father, Malcom Merilyn for quite a while.

Any reason Thea suffers amnesia? Or is it that this is just one of the plot holes of the TV series?

**Note: I am just half way through season 3, so please don't spoil the remaining season!**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Thea does indeed learn the secret of both her mother **and her brother** at the end of season 2, in fact she does so in episode 18 of season 2, called *Deathstroke*. Oliver looks definetely panicky when she says it - especially after she mentions that she has been lied to for years - but Thea then reveals that Slade only told her about *Malcolm Merlyn* being *her father*, a fact Oliver himself has in fact only learned very recently.

Slade never revealed to *Thea* that Oliver was the Arrow. He did however reveal that fact to *Laurel Lance* in the very same episode, which can easily get a bit jumbled in memory.

**Thea didn't have amnesia, because she didn't know before Oliver told her in *3x13 - Canaries***

Comment: I am confused here; then what is the secret that Thea learns about Oliver from Slade?

Comment: Both Moira and Oliver knew - and kept secret from Thea - that Malcolm was her father. So she learns just one secret, which is a secret of both her mother and Oliver. Although she is not aware of it, Oliver didn't actually keep that secret *for years*, just a few weeks, after Felicity found out and - after mentioning it to Walter, who tells her to stop looking into it, than confronting Moira, who just threatens her, before finally telling Oliver. Ollie also had just learned from Isabel - literally just that same episode iirc - that Robert had always known Thea wasn't his.

Answer (score 0):

In the arrow season 2 Thea Queen doesn't learn about her brother. She learns that her boyfriend Roy Harper was working with the Arrow. She left Starling City because she was sick of lies from her loved ones. Thea soon learns in season 3 episode 13 that her brother Oliver is the Arrow, when he takes her down to their base of operations.